# What does this actually mean? [Mainly on the for loop]

Tags: python

I must confess that I am not a great programmer (basically I am a beginner). I would like some help with understanding what is going in the code (which does work) but I need to ensure full comprehension before I feel ready to move on.

I have researched upon the 'for loop' but still, I cannot grasp what goes on in this part of code which was constructed with some help by observing answers to similar tasks.

**Please could someone tell me what exactly goes on specifically on the 'for loop'!**

This is the code:

```
while Checks != 5:
  for seqs in seqs:
    if seqs in UserPass:
      NumOfSeqs = UserPass.count(seqs)
      PointScore -= 5 * NumOfSeqs
      x += 1
  Checks += 1
print(PointScore)
```

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code, for us to understand its logic.

Comment: As well as fixing the indentation, you need to tell us what Checks, seqs and UserPass are. Also note that it's very very confusing to use the same name ('seqs') for the index variable as well as the thing it's iterating through.

Comment: Also, please try to build a title that represents your question that someone with different code but confused about the same underlying problem would recognize it as applicable *from the title*.

Comment: I don't really understand the what is used as the index variable, the 'Checks' variable is records the number of times a specific test has been complete. 'seqs' is a variable contained all possible QWERTY keyboard sequences. 'UserPass' is the password entered by the user through user input.

Comment: As for building a code sample that does as much as possible to help us help you -- see the docs on building a [mcve]. A good sample is the shortest possible thing (*minimal*) that produces a given problem when run in isolation (not depending on other variables or setup, thus *complete*) and which someone else can use to see the problem themselves or test a fix (thus *verifiable*).

Comment: I totally understand what you're saying, Charles Duffy, but this was something I really wanted to get off my chest and the only site I recognised as an effective way to find an easy to understand answer was on Stack Overflow. However, I will take on board your advice but for this occasion I do apologise that this is a highly isolated question

Comment: You need to fix the indentation of the `if` statement. Which statements after that are part of the `if`?

Comment: `for seqs in seqs:` is almost certainly not correct. You shouldn't use the same variable to hold the original list and the iteration variable. After the first iteration of the `while` loop, you lose the original value.

Comment: I just don't understand what is going on altogether, basically what I am trying to do is check the number of times a sequence of three consecutive letters on a QWERTY keyboard are entered in a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop like:

```
for x in y:
    some code here
```

means to repeatedly execute `some code here`, each time setting `x` to the next item in `y`. `y` can be any kind of iterable object: a list (it loops through the elements), a string (it loops through the characters), a dictionary (it loops through the keys), etc.

So when you write

```
for seqs in seqs:
```

the first iteration will set `seqs` to the first item in `seqs`, the second iteration will set it to the second item, and so on.

Since you're using the same variable for the original list and the iteration variable, when the loop is done `seqs` will hold the last item, not the original list. You almost certainly don't want to do that, you should use a different variable, e.g.

```
for seq in seqs:
```

Then use `seq` inside the loop to refer to the current element.

Comment: Thanks, that's been a huge help, I've attained a much better understanding on 'for loops'!

Comment: I can't believe I said anything that isn't explained at least as well in Python tutorials.